# Constraining shape of static dictionary while retaining type inference for it's exact shape

Tags: typescript, dictionary, type-inference, mapped-types

Let's say I have a static dictionary:

```
const myDict = {
  1: "one",
  2: "two",
}
```

TypeScript now infers that `typeof myDict` to exactly match the shape `myDict`, which is very nice, because IDE can autocomplete `myDict` keys for me

I would now like to constrain the dictionary so it must conform to the pattern `{ [k: number]?: string }`, but retaining the exact type inference, so I don't lose autocomplete. When I type it explicitly:

```
const myDict: { [k: number]?: string } = {
  1: "one",
  2: "two",
}
```

then `typeof myDict` changes from `{ 1: "one", 2: "two" }` to `{ [k: number]?: string }`, ruining my autocomplete. Is here a straight-forward way to do this?